# Factorial Programming Challenge Confusion

Tags: java, math

I recently completed a programming challenge that challenged us to get the factorial of 2015. After you calculate the factorial you are then to sum all the digits in the integer (in this case BigInteger).

When completed, I achieve the result of: 23,517

However, when I submitted it to the professor he states the correct result is: 26,532

I can't seem to find the problem at all. I've cross checked multiple sources and everything so far seems to point that I'm right. Could anyone find where my code went wrong?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

class toymeister {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + SumOf(FactorialOf(2015)));
    }

    public static BigInteger FactorialOf(int x){
        BigInteger Answer, intConvert;

        intConvert = new BigInteger("0");
        Answer = new BigInteger("1");       

        for(int i=1; i<=x;i++){
            intConvert = intConvert.valueOf(i);
            Answer = Answer.multiply(intConvert);
        }

        System.out.println("The Factorial Of " + x + " is: " + Answer);

        return Answer;
    }

    public static BigInteger SumOf(BigInteger y){
        BigInteger Sum = new BigInteger("0");

        while(y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
            Sum = Sum.add(y.mod(BigInteger.TEN));
            y = y.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        }

        return Sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, please follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): variable names should start with lowercase...

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=digitsum%28fact%282015%29%29 so 23517 is correct

Comment: Open your debugger friend.

Comment: Your professor is mistaken. Your answer is correct.

Comment: I second the comments on here. Your professor is wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is between the chair and the keyboard of the professor :p

Comment: Then, don’t use statements like `intConvert = intConvert.valueOf(i);`. `BigInteger.valueOf` is a `static` method and should be invoked as `intConvert = BigInteger.valueOf(i);`, then you don’t need a previous value at all. And since you know the existence of `BigInteger.ZERO`, why are you still wasting resources with `new BigInteger("0")` and `new BigInteger("1")` instead of `BigInteger.ZERO` and `BigInteger.ONE`?

Comment: Perfect example of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor

Comment: There is [an input that leads to the result 26,532](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=digitsum%28fact%282220%29%29). But `2220` is far off from `2015`. It’s unclear how the professor got to this different result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer 23517 [is correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=digitsum%28fact%282015%29%29). Still, you can simplify your code:

```
public static BigInteger factorialOf(int x) {
    BigInteger answer = BigInteger.ONE;
    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        answer = answer.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println("The Factorial Of " + x + " is: " + answer);
    return answer;
}

public static int sumOf(BigInteger y) {
    String digits = y.toString();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0, n = digits.length(); i<n; i++) sum += digits.charAt(i)-'0';
    return sum;
}
```

or, using Java 8:

```
public static BigInteger factorialOf(int x) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, x).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
        .reduce(BigInteger::multiply).orElse(BigInteger.ONE);
}
public static int sumOf(BigInteger y) {
    return y.toString().chars().map(i -> i-'0').sum();
}
```

Comment: I like this. (+1). I'd probably do `orElse(BigInteger.ONE)` to get the correct result for `x == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives way to simplify my code. I actually thought my code was simplified pretty well!

Comment: @Paul Boddington: good point